# How can I add error handling to the list monad? What data type do I need?

Tags: list, haskell, error-handling

```
let test2 =
        (fromDocument (doc :: Document) $/ element "body")
        >>= ($/ element "div")
        >>= (attributeIs "id" "content")
        >>= ($/ element "div")
        >>= (attributeIs "class" "box")
```

I'm using the `xml-conduit` library, I've get the above code which essentially filters a tree (an XML tree).

I'd like to add functionality to "error" if any of the binds (`>>=`) (if that is the correct word to use) return an empty list.

---

**What I've thought of doing:**

Both `element` and `attributeIs` return `Axis` which is `Cursor -> [Cursor]`

I'm finding it difficult to formulate the data type I need to use.
I was thinking of using `Either` to return `Left a` (`a` would be a function like `attributeIs "id" "content"`) or `Right Axis`.

But I wouldn't be able to return a `Either` type within the list monad if my understanding is correct.

Comment: It kinda works already. Remember that `join` for lists takes the Cartesian product of the inner lists, so if any one of the lists is empty then the resulting list will be empty

Comment: Correct, though instead of an empty list being returned I'd like an list of `functions` that did return a list with at least 1 `Axis`.

So the end goals is to identify which 'filter` caused the entire 'pipe'line' to return `[]`.

Comment: You should add this to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's for quick debugging, just use `Debug.Trace`. Otherwise you're asking for combining monads `List` and `Either String` : that's a [monad transformer](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/monad-transformers.html). Consider this simpler example on integers instead of XML trees :

```
plusOne :: Int -> [Int]
plusOne x = [x+1]

void :: Int -> [Int]
void x = if x <= 2 then [x] else []

listPipe :: [Int]
listPipe = [1,2,3] >>= plusOne >>= void
```

Some of the values in `listPipe` were cut by `void` and you'd like to know when this happens at runtime. Then your types become :

```
plusOne :: Int -> Either String [Int]
void :: Int -> Either String [Int]
listPipe :: Either String [Int]
```

which is isomorphic to the type `ListT (Either String) Int`. With wrapping it gives you :

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.List

void :: Int -> ListT (Either String) Int
void x = ListT $ if x <= 2 then Right [x] else Left "errorVoid"

plusOne :: Int -> ListT (Either String) Int
plusOne x = ListT $ Right [x+1]

listPipe :: Either String [Int]
listPipe = runListT $ ListT (Right [1,2,3]) >>= plusOne >>= void
```

and `listPipe = Left "errorVoid"`.